# Python: If I have a list of dicts{person_id,list,account}, how can I remove duplicate person_id and combine the list values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Here's the gist, I'm using Django to fill a PostgreSQL database to store user data from a third-party API. I'm using an API to get the data into Django so that I can automate the filling of the DB. I have the models built for the fields that need stored.

Here's where I need some help. I've create a list from an API response but I want to remove duplicate users and combine the lists, like this.

```
What I have now.
    {
        "person_id": "1",
        "account": "5",
        "list": "c"
    },
    {
        "person_id": "1",
        "account": "5",
        "list": "b"
    },
    {
        "person_id": "1",
        "account": "5",
        "list": "a"
    },
...
What i want
    {
        "person_id": "1",
        "account": "5",
        "list": ["a","b","c"]
    },
    {
        "person_id": "2",
        "account": "5",
        "list": ["a","c"]
    },
    {
        "person_id": "3",
        "account": "5"
        "list": ["a","b"]
    },
...
```

one API call I'm making is to get all users in a list and responds with:

```
API RESPONSE
{
    "records": [
        {
            "id": "asdafdgsdfhsdfh",
            "email": "email@email.com",
            "phone_number": "+1123123"
        },
        {
            "id": "asdafdgsdfhsdfh",
            "email": "email@email.com",
            "phone_number": "+1123123"
        },
       ...
 ],
 "marker":342523452
}
```

From that response I am iterating over each record and creating a dict to add to a list.

```
 def personA():
        return dict(
            person_id = record["id"],
            account = account,
            list = list   

r = requests.request('GET',f"{link}")
        resdata =r.json()
        for r in resdata:
            for record in resdata["records"]:
                listC = personA()
                listData.append(listC)         
    )
```

I am doing this for each list in the account, so some "person_id"'s show up many times, and some only once.

What would be the best way for me to create a list in the way that I'm going for?

Comment: Can a person have multiple accounts? If so, should those be grouped as well, or have separate entries in the final output?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark The person(people) in the list I am creating are essentially customers from a marketing list. The account in this case is referencing the account id that these lists are coming from, so they can be in multiple accounts within the database but that is out side of the scope of what I am doing here. The API call that is giving me the listData is only from one account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary will do here:

```py
# Grab the account_id from the first element in data. I'm assuming that the account names are the same across all data points, but this is not a serious concern per the comment.
account_id = data[0]["account"]
# We maintain a dictionary that maps from a person_id to a list of strings appearing in the list field for a given person_id.
person_id_elements = {}

# Read each data point into our dictionary.
for data_point in data:
    person_id = data_point["person_id"]
    list_element = data_point["list"]
    if person_id not in person_id_elements:
        person_id_elements[person_id] = []
    
    person_id_elements[person_id].append(list_element)

# Transform id_data into objects that observe the desired schema.
result = []
for person_id in person_id_elements:
    result.append({
        "person_id": person_id,
        "account": account_id,
        "list": sorted(person_id_elements[person_id]) # Sorted, as shown in the sample output.
    })

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mapping of the persons to the lists they appear in:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

separate_data = [
    {
        "person_id": "1",
        "account": "5",
        "list": "c"
    },
    {
        "person_id": "1",
        "account": "5",
        "list": "b"
    },
    {
        "person_id": "1",
        "account": "5",
        "list": "a"
    },
]
merged = defaultdict(list)
for record in separate_data:
    key = record["person_id"], record["account"]
    value = record["list"]
    merged[key].append(value)

results = [
    {
        "person_id": person_id,
        "account": account,
        "list": sorted(lists)
    } for (person_id, account), lists in merged.items()
]
```

gives

```
[{'account': '5', 'list': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'person_id': '1'}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately in this case since person_id is a string and not an integer it can not be used to iterate through records, but @BrokenBenchmark's solution  did just what I needed.

Comment: What does the `person_id` being a string has to do with iteration? I'm iterating over the dictionary I created before.

Comment: I tried the answer first and it worked, then I tried your suggestion and got a `typeerror: string indices must be integers` like I have many times before trying different ways of using **defaultdict**. I'm assuming since `record[person_id]` in `records` is a string.. it can not be used as a key in `records`, since iterables are indexed a number starting form 0 . I didn't look into it any more than the console.

Comment: @kadenee I suspect that was a problem with the input data. I've clarified the starting point in an update to my answer.